# If the matrix $A$ that is $m\times n$, has a colum that has only zeros then $Ax=0$ Has infinite solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Can anyone help me understand why is this true? 
I took a couple of examples and it somehow sorts out to be true, but I don't know how to somehow prove it and generalize. 
any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, prove that $Ax=0$ has infinite solutions iff $\text{rank}(A)<n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192594/if-a-is-an-m-times-n-matrix-prove-that-ax-0-has-infinite-solutions-iff)

Comment: If it has a zero column what does it say about it's rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $j$th column of $A$ is "all zeros", then all vectors $x=(0,0,\ldots,\alpha,\ldots,0)^T$ ($\alpha$ is at the $j$th place) are solutions, for every $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. This is because in each row, while multiplying $Ax$, $\alpha$ will be multiplied with the zero from $j$th column in $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ has a column with only zeros, $\text{rank} A < n$, so $\text{Ker} A \neq \emptyset$ which means there exists a $x$ such that $Ax = 0$.

Then by multiplying $x$ by any $\lambda$, you have a new $y$ such that $Ay = 0$.